# Passing install parameters to MSI installer with Puppet

Tags: windows, windows-installer, puppet

Programs are installed to PC running Windows 7.
In past I have installed a program like this:

```
msiexec /qn /i "C:\installer.msi"
```

I would like to automate this installation with Puppet.

```
package {'Program':
  ensure          => '3.1',
  source          => '\\server\installer.msi',
  install_options => [ '/qn', '/i'],
}
```

However there parameters are not accept by installer. Either Puppet gives error of "invalid command line arguments" or parameters simply wont be applied.

I have tried using different syntaxes: all parameters inside same quotes, different order of parameters, only one parameter at the time... But nothing has worked.

What is the correct way of passing them?

Comment: Can you run with the `--debug` flag and share the output that pertains to the `Package[Program]` resource? (Please edit your question to include it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the puppet windows package provider already passes the arguments /i and /qn. msiexec fails if you pass /i twice. Try running it without the install options.